# Can you have too much drainage in a garden?

Tags: drainage

I plan on using some of these drainage bricks to build a retaining wall.

[image]

The installation of the drainage bricks recommends that a drainage layer is used to route the water away from the base of the inner wall.

I am thinking to lay a very wide drainage layer, however my concern is that I "Dry Up" my garden.

is it possible for me to over-drain my garden, whereby any moisture absorbed into the ground is routed away too quickly?

is there any drainage guide which i can apply?

Comment: this amount of work and material is usually only seen in commercial retaining walls that are over 6 feet tall.  What are the specifications for your wall, and what kind of soil do you have, where do you live, how deep does the frost go?

Comment: Yes, it is possible to have too much drainage, but it depends what you want to grow and what your average rainfall is. If you want lots of alpines, they'll love it.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is possible to have too much drainage.  If you have a good soil though that will retain enough moisture to reduce your watering frequency. If you have sandy soil you might find yourself having to water frequently.